# Dynamically updating filters in a dashboard

Tags: jira, reporting

The team I'm on has a couple of JIRA dashboards for our projects tracking tickets that were completed. Our process is to create a filter for that weeks completed issues, and then create a new dashboard linked to that filter. We end up with a dashboard like this, ProjectA Week N.

We automatically create the filter, but we're not sure how we can automatically create the related dashboard. One option might be to automatically create the dashboard ProjectA Week N. Another option might be to have a ProjectA dashboard with an automatically updated drop down menu to switch between weeks.

How should we automate our dashboards?

Comment: Do you really want to set up (and keep) dashboards for every week and for all projects (so number of projects * weeks since beginning)? Or do you just need a dashboard per project that automatically shows the current week's data (i.e. based on a filter that dynamically filters for issues completed in the current week)?

Comment: As @matt_jay mentions above, you might not be using dashboards appropriately. A Dashboard is something expected to be fairly stable. If can look at the data historically if you want, but always in a single dashboard. Notice that there's a plethora of dashboard plugins, you may only achieve what you need using them.

Answer (score 0):

As @matt_jay mentioned you should have rather static dashboard not bunch of dashboards. Did you tried swimlanes feature ?
You could create one dashboard and create swimlanes with filters. We are doing such thing to sort out tasks by epics.
Then you could just update the filters associated with the swim lane and dashboard will be automatically updated for proper time period or use static filter saying NO Older than XXX days etc.